# Siging an exe with Yubikey error Error: SignerSign() failed

Tags: code-signing, signtool, yubico, yubikey

I have bought an EV signing from ssl.com.
I have a Yubikey 5 NFC, so I tried to load the signature into my Yubikey with all the attestation and stuff.

https://www.ssl.com/how-to/key-generation-and-attestation-with-yubikey/

Everything seems good, `certmgr` shows the certificate.

But when trying to sign an EXE, I am getting the next error:

> "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146435068/0x80100004)

To solve it, I tried to install the Yubikey smart card [minidriver](https://www.yubico.com/support/download/smart-card-drivers-tools/), and then I started to get the next error:

> "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146435071/0x80100001)

And sometimes, I started getting the UI error as seen in this Stack Overflow [detailed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102834/yubikey-piv-the-smartcard-cannot-perform-the-requested-operation):

> The smartcard cannot perform the requested operation`

Things I have done to try to solve this problem:

1. Recreate the attestation and reinstall the signature on Yubikey.
2. Resetting the Yubikey PIV and restoring everything to default, including repeating step number #1.
3. Installing/uninstalling the Yubikey smart card minidriver, and tried to use Yubikey with and without the minidriver.
4. Try to attest/install the signature from the command line, Yubikeymanager, and ssl.com manager.
5. Tried all the steps here both on Windows 11, and Windows 10.

#### List of dead ends

- following [Yubikey old article](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016614840-Code-Signing-with-the-YubiKey-on-Windows) about codesigning in Windows from 2020, it mentions pfx file, and since 2023, the private key should be created inside the Yubikey PIV, so this article is not relevant.
- trying various methods from Yubico GitHub issues, nothing helps, and it ends in 2018 so 6 years ago before Yubikey 5 released, https://github.com/Yubico/yubikey-piv-manager/issues/24